# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray when receiving JSON code on Android App

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to read JSON data from a localhost PHP file. It successfully connects but I get the error

`05-27 15:40:24.108: E/log_tag(17146): Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value {"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

When I open the PHP script in my browser it successfully displays `{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }`

```
package com.example.testexternaldatabase;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView resultView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults(); // STRICT MODE ENABLED
    resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    getData();
}

public void getData() {
    String result = "";
    InputStream isr = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mstreetllc.com/Lab.asp"); // YOUR PHP
                                                                    // SCRIPT
                                                                    // ADDRESS
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        isr = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        isr.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    try {

        String s = "";
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s + "Name : " + json.getString("name") + "\n"
                    + "Email : " + json.getString("email") + "\n\n";
        }

        resultView.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}` is an object not an array

Comment: Is there anyway I can fix this to read the data?

Comment: Use `new JSONObject(result)` instead of `new JSONArray(result)`.

Comment: @nick : Please look at http://www.json.org it explains pretty much everything you need to know about JSON on a single page.

Comment: I get an error when I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert what is considered a JSONObject directly into a JSONArray, which is throwing the error you're getting.

A JSONObject would start and and with the brackets { and }, respectively. A JSONArray would start and end with [ and ], respectively, as well as be deliminated by commas, similar to the fields in a JSONObject.

E.g. JSONObject:

```
{ 
    "firstName":"John", 
    "lastName":"Doe" 
}
```

E.g JSONArray containing 2 of your original objects inside a JSONObject:

```
{ 
    "the_name_of_your_json_array": [
         { 
              "firstName":"John", 
              "lastName":"Doe" 
          },
         { 
              "firstName":"John", 
              "lastName":"Doe" 
          }
    ]
}
```

Now, to fix your code, since you're only receiving a single JSONObject:

```
    String s = "";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    s = s + "Name : " + json.getString("name") + "\n" + "Email : " + json.getString("email") + "\n\n";
```

If you're actually returning an array of data (or if that's your intention), it will still be wrapped inside a JSONObject, and would have to be adjusted like so:

```
    String s = "";
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONObject(result).getJSONArray("the_name_of_your_json_array");
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        s = s + "Name : " + json.getString("name") + "\n" + "Email : " + json.getString("email") + "\n\n";
    }
```

And inside your PHP Script, you would want to encode like so:

```
json_encode(array('the_name_of_your_json_array' => $your_original_array_of_data));
```

Don't forget to replace the variable names with whatever you're actually using, and hopefully I was descriptive enough without comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
// parse json data
try {

    String s = "";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

    s = s + "First Name : " + json.getString("firstName") + "\n"
                + "Last Name : " + json.getString("lastName") + "\n\n";
    resultView.setText(s);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
}
```